# Como fazer gráficos dinâmicos no Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um programa para a Raspberry Pi que faz a leitura de sensores de temperatura e armazena essas leituras em um buffer. Preciso fazer um gráfico dinâmico que mostre a relação entre temperatura x tempo atuais. Tentei fazer utilizando a biblioteca matplotlib, mas não consigo atualizar esse gráfico.

No código abaixo, quando uso o método append vou acrescentando os valores obtidos na leitura de temperatura.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temperatura = [10, 20, 30 ,40 , 50 ,60 , 70, 80]

tempo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

plt.plot(tempo, temperatura )

plt.ylabel('Temperatura (C°)')

plt.xlabel('Tempo (S)')

plt.show()

temperatura.append(90)

tempo.append(9)

plt.plot(tempo, temperatura )

plt.show()
```

Ao executar o programa é apresentado o gráfico com os valores iniciais, mas somente ao fechar o gráfico é que abre o outro gráfico com os valores atualizados!

Comment: Você tem dois `plt.show()` no seu código.

Comment: Sim, para tentar atualizar o gráfico!

Comment: De acordo com a documentação é possível usar `plt.show(block=False)` para que ele não fique aguardando o desenho ser fechado.

Comment: Disse "de acordo com a documentação" pois nela diz que é uma implementação experimental :-)

Comment: Nesse link tem o que você procura https://pythonprogramming.net/python-matplotlib-live-updating-graphs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a função `animation` do `matplotlib` é possível fazer de maneira simples, utilizando o seu código criei um exemplo, estou pegando a temperatura de modo randômico, valores aleatórios entre `0` e `100` para demonstrar, o tempo neste caso está sendo incrementado por `+1`, segue um pequeno `gif` do código rodando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
ys = [10, 20, 30 ,40 , 50 ,60 , 70, 80]


#incremento partindo dos últimos valores de cada lista
temperatura=80
tempo=8;

#função para animar
def animate(i, xs, ys):
    global temperatura
    global tempo

    #incremento
    #temperatura= temperatura+10
    temperatura= randint(0, 100)
    tempo = tempo + 1

    #append índice do tempo e temperatura
    xs.append(tempo)
    ys.append(temperatura)


    # desenhar x e y
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)


    plt.title('Temperatura Atual e Tempo')
    plt.ylabel('Temperatura')

# altere o valor do interval para que que o frame seja atualizado de maneira mais rápida ou não
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```